# Having real trouble installing community toolbox

Tags: matlab

I can't install coco for the life of me.
I am familiar with MATLAB, but I have never installed a toolbox, and that's where I'm having problems. I want to install coco. I have installed MATLAB 2012b, a compatible version, and have followed the video instructions exactly however nothing is happening.

How do I know if it's all installed correctly?

Comment: This question is too broad. Do you have particular problem, error message that we can help you with?

Comment: No error message, I am not sure how to launch a community toolbox.